# Preserving resolution while creating image using GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal

I have to save /Export raster layer to image . How this can be done using Python Script .

I can do this with GDAL script but this creates an image with low resolution

```
 gdal_translate -of GTiff abc.tif out.jpeg
```

or,

```
 gdal_translate -of JPEG -B 1 -B 2 -B 3 abc.tif out.jpeg
```

Is there any way to preserve the resolution while creating image using GDAL ?

Comment: `gdal_translate -of GTiff abc.tif out.jpeg` will output a GeoTiff called `out.jpeg`. It won't actually be JPEG format.

Answer (score 3):

What you are showing shouldn't be changing the *resolution* of the image in terms of the georeferencing, but is actually *compressing* the image.

You can set the level of compression using a creation option called `QUALITY` ([GDAL jpeg docs](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg.html)).

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG -co "QUALITY=95" abc.tif out.jpeg
```

Comment: i tried it but shows Input File size is 219,163                                                 0Error 6 :JPEG Driver doesn't support 2 bands. Must be 1 (grey) ,3 (RGB) ,or 4 Bands.

Comment: Due to jpeg's specs, it will need 1, 3, or 4 bands. Either duplicate one of the input bands into another channel or save as two separate raster files. ([gdal_translate docs](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)) GeoTiffs don't have this requirement, so consider using that format if it is acceptable within the workflow.